# Compare count of characters with a constant value, then execute next statement

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting

I have a PowerShell script where I get the count of certain string from a file, then go to next step or execute next step only if the string count is 30.

I do have the code for getting the count of the string, as well the code for executing the next step. The only thing missing is to incorporate `if` statement.

---

To get the count of string, I am using the following:

```
$FileContent = Get-Content "YourFile.txt"
$Matches = Select-String -InputObject $FileContent -Pattern "/export" -AllMatches
```

To do the next step, I am using following;

```
"d:/scripts/plink.exe" -ssh %1 -l hpov -pw NDIA123 -m %com%|find "host" >>%lnm%
```

---

How to include `if` condition in between above two codes, so that last command will follow, only if the count of the string is more than 30?

Comment: Which PowerShell Version are you using? What does this have to do with remoting? Where is your code to get the count of string?

Comment: Not to mention that the second command is batch, not PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

First off, don't use `$Matches` for anything user-defined - it's [an automatic variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx).

With that out of the way: since `Select-String` may return multiple lines, you should sort them by length and test the length of the longest one:

```
$FileContent = Get-Content "YourFile.txt"
$LongestMatch = Select-String -InputObject $FileContent -Pattern "/export" -AllMatches |Sort-Object {$_.Line.Length} |Select-Object -Last 1

if($LongestMatch.Line.Length -gt 30){
    # We found a match in a string longer than 30 chars!
    # run plink here!
}
```

Comment: Hi Mathias, I will give it a try once I have access to the system. I will update you on the outcome later :)

Answer (score 0):

This may be too simplistic. I feel like there is something I must have missed in the question.

```
$FileContent = Get-Content "YourFile.txt"
$Matches = Select-String -InputObject $FileContent -Pattern "/export" -AllMatches

if ($Matches -eq 30) {
    & "d:/scripts/plink.exe" -ssh %1 -l hpov -pw NDIA123 -m %com%|find "host" >>%lnm%
}
```

Comment: Hi Liturgist, I will give it a try once I have access to the system. I will update you on the outcome later :)